# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception, surfaceholder

I've searched about this problem for two days. I know that this is caused by some silly mistake but i'm unable to find that thing. It would be great, if someone helps me. Here is snippet

```
private void draw() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();;

        try {
            update(c);
            updateText(c);     //These are the effects like snowing or bouncing
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);   //This is line no. 151
        }

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (mVisible) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10);
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is whithin above method. Here is logcat:

```
 11-18 11:29:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-18 11:29:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)

11-18 11:29:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:215)

11-18 11:29:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at com.example.livewallpaper.SnowEffect$MyBounce.draw(SnowEffect.java:151)

11-18 11:29:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at com.example.livewallpaper.SnowEffect$MyBounce.access$0(SnowEffect.java:141)

11-18 11:29:15.145: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at com.example.livewallpaper.SnowEffect$MyBounce$1.run(SnowEffect.java:55)
```

Comment: what is getSurfaceHolder() on second line?

Comment: its a inbuilt method which provides you a surface on which the wallpaper is to be drawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

If someone got stuck in same problem, here is the solution, it was a really silly mistake. Update your manifest file.

```
<activity
      android:name="com.yourpackage.Prefs"
      android:exported="true" >
      <intent-filter>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Don't forget to add `android:exported="true"`. I missed it actually!**

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! You saved me from a mental hospital.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine.

Comment: @PM25793 Pls help. My manifest already has this line android:exported="true". But, still I am getting this Exception. What should i do?

Comment: check your code twice :) there would be something u missing.